# why we pass this in Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am new in XML. Here I don't understand that why we pass "this" to `myfunction()`. I am waiting for your informative answers. Looking forward.

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  txt = "";
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ARTIST");
  for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
    txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Comment: Here, `this` refers to the `XMLHttpRequest` Object `xmlhttp`

Comment: `this` refers to the `xmlhttp` object. It's passed so that the callback can access `responseXML` on the `xmlhttp` object.

Comment: `this` is called the "context" of the function. A good primer on it is the [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the current context.

`this` is then passed into `myFunction()` as an argument.

`myFunction()` then takes the Object (now called `xml`) and does *stuff* with it.

To get technical, take a look at the MDN page describing `XMLHHttpRequest()` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

All the list of properties are in the current context. You will notice one of them being `responseXML`. This is the attribute you are referring to in your code:

```
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `this` is not related to scope at all. It is related to binding which is a completely different concept.

Comment: @slebetman Mistake in my choice of wording. "Context" is a better word to describe it. Updated.